# after adding select2 plugin to select option . Laravel Livewire search not working

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I am working with laravel 8 and livewire. After adding select2 to a dropdown select , livewire search not working.

this is livewire

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Album;

use App\Models\Album;
use domain\Facades\Gallery\GalleryFacade;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class SearchAlbum extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $searchTerm;
   

    public function render()
    {
        $galleries = GalleryFacade::all();
        $searchTerm = '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%';
        $gallery_id = $this->gallery_id;
       
            return view('livewire.album.search-album', [
                'albums' => Album::where('gallery_id', '=', $gallery_id)->where('name', 'like', $searchTerm)->paginate(12),
                'galleries' => $galleries,
            ]);
        
    }
}
```

and this is the select options in blade

```js
 $('#select-gallery').select2({
        placeholder: "Select A Gallery",
    });
```

```html
<select id="select-gallery" class="custom-select" name="gallery_id" wire:model="gallery_id">
                            <option></option>
                            @foreach ($galleries as $gallery)
                            <option value="{{ $gallery->id }}">{{ $gallery->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

I want to retrieve all the albums related to selected gallery. But when select a gallery it does not search. But When using select option without select2 plugin it works.

Any one can help to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

first of all take public variable named **gallery_id** in your **SearchAlbum** class.

After that you have to make following changes in blade and jquery:

**Blade:**

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <select id="select-gallery" class="custom-select" name="gallery_id" 
     wire:model="gallery_id">
        <option value="">Select Gallery</option>
        @foreach ($galleries as $gallery)
          <option value="{{ $gallery->id }}">{{ $gallery->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-gallery').select2();
        $('#select-gallery').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('#select-gallery').select2("val");
            @this.set('gallery_id', data);
        });
    });
</script>
```